# Find $s^4-18s^2-8s$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Let $a,b,c$ be the roots of $x^3-9x^2+11x-1=0$, and let $s=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}$. Find $s^4-18s^2-8s$.

$s^4 - 18s^2 - 8s = (s)(s + 4)(s - 2 + \sqrt{6})(s - 2 - \sqrt{6})$

$P(x) = (x - a)(x - b)(x - c)$

From Vieta's formulas:

$a + b+ c = 9$

$abc = 1$

$ab + ac + bc = 11$

Actually, if $y = \sqrt{x}$ then if $y$ is a root, the function must map $y \to x$, which means, let $x \to x^2$ to get:

$P_2(x) = x^6 - 9x^4 + 11x^2 - 1 = 0$.

Then $s = \sum \text{roots } P_2(x) = 0$.

But then $s^4 - 18s^2 - 8s = 0$? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you create the new polynomial so that you can exploit Vieta's you inadvertently add three new roots. While three of the roots are $\sqrt{a}$, $\sqrt{b}$, and $\sqrt{c}$, the new polynomial also has roots $-\sqrt{a}$, $-\sqrt{b}$, and $-\sqrt{c}$. Adding all of these up we get 0; this isn't the value of $s$ since $s$ is only the sum of the positive square roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us instead see how the cubic whose roots are squares of the roots of $x^3-sx^2+ tx- 1$ (why?) would look like.  Using Vieta, this is easily written as:
$$x^3-(s^2-2t)x^2+(t^2-2s)x-1$$

Comparing with our given cubic, we get $s^2-2t = 9$ and $t^2-2s = 11$ which on eliminating $t$ gives us $s^4 -18s^2-8s = -37$.

Answer (score 0):

$$s=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\\\Rightarrow s^2=a+b+c+2\sqrt{ab}+2\sqrt{bc}+2\sqrt{ca}\\\Rightarrow s^2-9=2(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca})\\\Rightarrow s^4-18s^2+81=(s^2-9)^2=4(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca})^2=4(ab+bc+ca)+8\sqrt{abc}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})\\\Rightarrow s^4-18s^2+81=4\cdot11+8\cdot 1\cdot s\\\Rightarrow s^4-18s^2-8s=44-81=-37$$